# Can I use a modfied copy of the Android OS in a commercial application?

Tags: copyright

I have a question regarding the use of Android.

We want to sell devices, that are equipped with a modified Android-System.

- Some things are restricted
- Some apps are preinstalled
- We use the company logo when booting the system.

Is there something we need to consider in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android OS is Open Source (formally known as Android Open Source Project AOSP http://source.android.com/ ), which means anyone can "fork" it into their own version of the OS. You can't use the word Android, the same font etc.; check the license: http://developer.android.com/legal.html

You can also combine your fork with other Open Source or proprietary software on a hardware device with the relevant Open Source and other licenses.

Android is a catch-all name for the OS which is really two parts: the "open" Android Open Source Project (AOSP), which forms the foundation of the OS, and the closed source proprietary services from Google, which are Google-branded apps, like Gmail, Maps, etc.

The use of Google services and APIs in conjunction with any fork or version of Android requires licensing from Google.

One example of a Android OS fork that does not use Google services is Amazon's Kindle Fire. Amazon used AOSP but developed their own app store, web browser, e-mail, etc.

You're free to use AOSP with your own Apps, own sets of functions and logos, as long as you include the relevant software licenses, as per the license linked above.

*One legal caveat: if you are developing a device and OS fork and related software for sale, you should be sure and get a clear opinion from a attorney for your own records and protection and write a clear EULA to include with your software.*